# Create full heirarchical path from objects

Tags: path, hierarchical-data

So here is my issue.  I have objects that have a name property and a parentId property.  What I would like to do is to construct a string containing the full hierarchical path, similar to a filepath (\grandparent\parent\child).

```
SomeObject:
  public var parentId:String;
  public var someObjectName:String;
```

I can't seem to figure out a way that doesn't scale horribly or redo a lot of work.

Current Idea:  Add a function called getFullPathArray that would look like this

```
    getFullPath(parentIdHashMap:Map,returnArray:Array):Array
    {
         returnArray.addFirst(this.someObjectName);
         if( parentId != null )  
         {
             var parentSomeObject = parentIdHashMap[this.parentId]
             parentSomeObject(parentIdHashMap,returnArray)             
         }
         return returnArray
    }
```

The problem with this function is that every someObject would be touched multiple times based on the number of descendents which just seems like trouble.

Second Idea:

Attach a level identifier to my model.  Then I can order and group by level and proceed downward. The issue I see with this is that the level has to be maintained.  This isn't a problem, it's just extra logic for me to break and hose up later down on the line.

I know this problem is solved multiple times in multiple arenas but I can't seem to find a good way that isn't concerned with creating and maintaining a data structure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use recursion, some thing like so:

```
getFullPath(obj):String
    {      
         if( parentId != null )  
         {
             var path = getFullPath(parentIdHashMap[this.parentId]) + "/" + someObjectName;
             return path;             
         } else
         {
           return someObjectName;
          }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of using recursion, but then I end up touching every object.  But I do think the solution lies in object recursion, I just have to figure out a way to flag which parents and grandparents already have their paths set, and which ones I need to continue to move up the tree with.